# How can I conditionally replace variable values with values from neighboring observations in ordered data?

Tags: r, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am attempting to recreate the rank and replace method described in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2875762/pdf/hesr0045-0825.pdf) in R. I reached out to the study author for help, but they used Stata (which I am much less familiar with than R) and could only provide example code for that program.

The method goes like this:

1. A survey weighted generalized linear model is fit using all independent variables.
2. An index score is calculated for each observation to summarize the value of a subset of the independent variables. This takes the form of the sum of each relevant term in the model from step 1.
3. Within each race group, individuals are assigned a survey weighted ranking based on their index score from step 2.
4. For observations representing individuals with minority race, each observation's index score is replaced by that from the equivalently ranked observation with non-white race.
5. The model from step 1 is reapplied to the transformed data to predict differences in outcome between each race group.

The step I'm struggling with is number 4. I looked at other answers on SO but did not find them helpful, but if you know of one that is applicable I'd be very happy to be directed to it.

I'm starting with a dataset that already contains the original index variable, has the survey weighted rank variable, and is ordered by that rank variable. Race is indicated with dichotomous variables `black` and `white`, where a value of 1 indicates having that race.

#### Step 4a (successful):

I know I can create a new, index variable with `ifelse`. If an observation (rowid = 2, for example) has black race and the one above it (rowid = 1) has white race, I want to replace the new index score for the observation with black race (rowid = 2) with the value for the original index variable in the observation with white race (rowid = 1).

So, I start with this code:

```
data$index_new <- ifelse((data$black == 1 & lag(data$white) == 1), lag(data$index_orig), NA)
```

Which gives me something like this:

| rowid | rank_weighted | black | white | index_orig | index_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.26 | 0 | 1 | -5.72 | NA |
| 2 | 0.28 | 1 | 0 | -5.50 | -5.72 |
| 3 | 0.46 | 1 | 0 | -5.66 | NA |
| 4 | 0.66 | 0 | 1 | -5.64 | NA |
| 5 | 0.74 | 0 | 1 | -5.50 | NA |
| 6 | 0.81 | 1 | 0 | -5.60 | -5.50 |
| 7 | 0.85 | 1 | 0 | -5.58 | NA |
| 8 | 1.12 | 1 | 0 | -5.50 | NA |
| 9 | 1.41 | 0 | 1 | -5.57 | NA |
| 10 | 1.42 | 1 | 0 | -5.55 | -5.57 |

That worked as desired.

#### Step 4b (unsuccessful):

Now I need to address rows 3, 7, and 8. I ultimately do not want any observation with black race to have NA for the new index. Those observations still have NAs in the new index variable because the observation directly above them does not have white race. To solve that, I want to search the observations below them to locate the nearest one with white race and use that observation's index value. I want achieve this result:

| rowid | rank_weighted | black | white | index_orig | index_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.26 | 0 | 1 | -5.72 | NA |
| 2 | 0.28 | 1 | 0 | -5.50 | -5.72 |
| 3 | 0.46 | 1 | 0 | -5.66 | -5.64 |
| 4 | 0.66 | 0 | 1 | -5.64 | NA |
| 5 | 0.74 | 0 | 1 | -5.50 | NA |
| 6 | 0.81 | 1 | 0 | -5.60 | -5.50 |
| 7 | 0.85 | 1 | 0 | -5.58 | -5.57 |
| 8 | 1.12 | 1 | 0 | -5.50 | -5.57 |
| 9 | 1.41 | 0 | 1 | -5.57 | NA |
| 10 | 1.42 | 1 | 0 | -5.55 | -5.57 |

Note that row 3 value for the new index variable came from the original index for row 4. The value for the new index variable in both rows 7 and 8 came from the original index for row 9.

My data is very large and it is not practical to manually specify the row from which to copy to the original index value. It is also possible that there could be many several observations in a row that have black race, so the code will have to search several observations to find the next one with white race. I believe this can be done with a while loop, but have never written one this complex. The example Stata code I was given also uses a while loop.

Here is what the **example Stata code** does, if that's at all helpful:

```
local i=2
while `i'<15     {   
replace index_new=index_orig[(_n-`i')] if black==1 & white[_n-`i']==1 & index_new==. 
    local i=`i'+1 
    set more off
}
```

I have tried to replicate that code in R, since I'm not familiar with while loops like this one, but it does not provide the desired results. It runs without errors but doesn't replace any values in the dataset at all. Here is one example of what I have been trying **in R**:

```
val <- 2
while (val < 15)
{
  data$index_new <- ifelse((data$black == 1 & lead(data$white, n = val) == 1 & is.na(data$index_new == T)), lead(data$index_orig, n = val), data$index_new)
  val = val + 1
}
```

I don't understand why that loop doesn't work. How can I write a while loop that will achieve these results? Here is some sample data which is similar to the first table I provided above, in case that's helpful:

```
structure(list(black = structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
), format.stata = "%9.0g"), white = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), rank_weighted = c(0.264, 
0.278, 0.46, 0.656, 0.743, 0.813, 0.858, 1.124, 1.41, 1.416, 
1.608, 1.762, 1.962, 2.008, 2.128, 2.506, 2.513, 2.737, 2.967, 
3.158, 3.339, 3.682, 3.999, 4.057, 4.149, 4.274, 4.406, 4.481, 
4.558, 4.872), index_orig = structure(c(-5.718, -5.502, -5.659, 
-5.636, -5.634, -5.502, -5.598, -5.584, -5.502, -5.572, -5.549, 
-5.544, -5.544, -5.502, -5.535, -5.484, -5.533, -5.527, -5.515, 
-5.453, -5.51, -5.502, -5.502, -5.426, -5.502, -5.502, -5.502, 
-5.409, -5.502, -5.502), format.stata = "%10.0g"), index_new = c(NA, 
-5.718, NA, NA, NA, -5.634, NA, NA, NA, -5.502, NA, NA, NA, -5.544, 
NA, -5.535, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.502, NA, NA, NA, -5.502, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat a simple `if_else` operation as many times as you want:

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(index_new = if_else(black == 1 & lead(black) == 0 & is.na(index_new), lead(index_orig), index_new))

for (i in seq(15)) {
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(index_new = if_else(black == 1 & lead(black) == 1 & is.na(index_new), lead(index_new), index_new))
}

#    rowid rank_weighted black white index_orig index_new
# 1      1          0.26     0     1      -5.72        NA
# 2      2          0.28     1     0      -5.50     -5.72
# 3      3          0.46     1     0      -5.66     -5.64
# 4      4          0.66     0     1      -5.64        NA
# 5      5          0.74     0     1      -5.50        NA
# 6      6          0.81     1     0      -5.60     -5.50
# 7      7          0.85     1     0      -5.58     -5.57
# 8      8          1.12     1     0      -5.50     -5.57
# 9      9          1.41     0     1      -5.57        NA
# 10    10          1.42     1     0      -5.55     -5.57
```

The first step modifies the black 1s followed by 0s, and then the for loop modifies those that continue the chain above.

EDIT:

Full sample script:

```r
data <- structure(list(black = structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
), format.stata = "%9.0g"), white = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1), format.stata = "%9.0g"), rank_weighted = c(0.264, 
0.278, 0.46, 0.656, 0.743, 0.813, 0.858, 1.124, 1.41, 1.416, 
1.608, 1.762, 1.962, 2.008, 2.128, 2.506, 2.513, 2.737, 2.967, 
3.158, 3.339, 3.682, 3.999, 4.057, 4.149, 4.274, 4.406, 4.481, 
4.558, 4.872), index_orig = structure(c(-5.718, -5.502, -5.659, 
-5.636, -5.634, -5.502, -5.598, -5.584, -5.502, -5.572, -5.549, 
-5.544, -5.544, -5.502, -5.535, -5.484, -5.533, -5.527, -5.515, 
-5.453, -5.51, -5.502, -5.502, -5.426, -5.502, -5.502, -5.502, 
-5.409, -5.502, -5.502), format.stata = "%10.0g"), index_new = c(NA, 
-5.718, NA, NA, NA, -5.634, NA, NA, NA, -5.502, NA, NA, NA, -5.544, 
NA, -5.535, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.502, NA, NA, NA, -5.502, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(index_new = if_else(black == 1 & lead(black) == 0 & is.na(index_new), lead(index_orig), index_new))

for (i in seq(15)) {
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(index_new = if_else(black == 1 & lead(black) == 1 & is.na(index_new), lead(index_new), index_new))
}

print(data, n = 40)

# A tibble: 30 × 5
   black white rank_weighted index_orig index_new
   <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     0     1         0.264      -5.72     NA   
 2     1     0         0.278      -5.50     -5.72
 3     1     0         0.46       -5.66     -5.64
 4     0     1         0.656      -5.64     NA   
 5     0     1         0.743      -5.63     NA   
 6     1     0         0.813      -5.50     -5.63
 7     1     0         0.858      -5.60     -5.50
 8     1     0         1.12       -5.58     -5.50
 9     0     1         1.41       -5.50     NA   
10     1     0         1.42       -5.57     -5.50
11     0     1         1.61       -5.55     NA   
12     0     1         1.76       -5.54     NA   
13     0     1         1.96       -5.54     NA   
14     1     0         2.01       -5.50     -5.54
15     0     1         2.13       -5.54     NA   
16     1     0         2.51       -5.48     -5.54
17     1     0         2.51       -5.53     -5.51
18     1     0         2.74       -5.53     -5.51
19     1     0         2.97       -5.52     -5.51
20     1     0         3.16       -5.45     -5.51
21     0     1         3.34       -5.51     NA   
22     0     1         3.68       -5.50     NA   
23     0     1         4.00       -5.50     NA   
24     1     0         4.06       -5.43     -5.50
25     0     1         4.15       -5.50     NA   
26     0     1         4.27       -5.50     NA   
27     0     1         4.41       -5.50     NA   
28     1     0         4.48       -5.41     -5.50
29     1     0         4.56       -5.50     -5.50
30     0     1         4.87       -5.50     NA
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to me and runs without errors. It does replace a lot of values, but for some reason is still leaving NAs in the data. I increased to seq(30) but got the same results. Do you have any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Your expected output also has NA values. Feel free to add more input data and expected output to your post, and highlight any discrepancies from what my code outputs and how it should be.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. There are still NA values in the index_new variable for some observations with black race, which I do not want. When your suggested code is run on the data I provided with dput, you'll see that in rows 7 and 17-19. Instead of NA for index_new in row 7, as an example, it should be -5.502. I think the for loop only replaces values if the observation immediately below has white race, and is not actually searching further than that.

Comment: Using your dput data and the exact script in my edits, I cannot reproduce this. All black rows have a valid index_new value.

Comment: Likely you omitted the first code chunk before the loop.